# When $g \circ f$ is an extremal monomorphism, $f$ must be an extremal monomorphism. Why?

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

I couldn't prove part (2) of the proposition 7.62 in Adameck's book (*Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats*). It states that if $g \circ f$ is assumed to be an extremal monomorphism, then the rightmost morphism, $f$ must be an extremal monomorphism too. I could not prove it. Is there any straightforward proof?

Thanks very much,

Comment: *extremal* monomorphism, I presume? A monomorphism $f$ is extremal if whenever $f=gh$ for some epimorphism $h$, then $h$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The authors write that the proof is immediate and I agree. Show that $f$ is mono and extremality follows right away.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your comment. Actually, I tried to follow your advice, but i still cannot prove it. If $g \circ f$ is a monomorphism, it is easy to show that $f$ must be a monomorphism. It is proved in proposition 7.34 in that book. But I can't see how extremality is proved. To my eyes the proof given in 7.34 of Adameck's book does not entail extremality.

Comment: Apply the definition of extremality. If $f = uh$ for some epimorphism $h$, then $gf = (gu)h$. What do we conclude about $h$ from extremality of $gf$?

Comment: We conclude that $h$ is an isomorphism; because extremality of $g \circ f$ is our assumption. Yes, it works. I thank you very much; the way it was proved was interesting indeed. Thanks!